# Elasticsearch on Jhipster, Spring

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot, jhipster

Can someone give me example for using **Elasticsearch** in **jHipster** or in **Spring-boot**?

I have already generated entity using jHipster. There are input with placeholder :query !

```
/**
     * SEARCH  /_search/samples/:query -> search for the sample corresponding
     * to the query.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/_search/samples/{query}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public List<Sample> search(@PathVariable String query) {
        return StreamSupport
            .stream(sampleSearchRepository.search(queryString(query)).spliterator(), false)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

How can use the elasticsearch ?

Here some script that i found in generated Entity!

I have already tried placing **Object**, **q=field:value**, **Array with elastic format** and always got empty **Array**.

Sorry for bad english!.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it seems that your index is empty. If you add entities programmatically (i.e. not from the interface), be sure to save them in the search repository as well.

Example :

```
Sample sample = new Sample();
sample.setName("bar");
sample = sampleRepository.save(sample);
sampleSearchRepository.save(sample);
```

You need to reaffect sample to get the id generated by Hibernate correctly indexed in elasticsearch.

**UPDATE 10/02/2016**

There is now a [JHipster module to reindex elasticsearch repositories](http://jhipster.github.io/modules/marketplace/#/details/generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer).

Answer (score 0):

You should just do a GET call to the url by substituting the placeolder with the string that you want to search in the 'sample' entity.

You can test the call by using a rest client (eg. restclient plugin for firefox) or curl.
The url should be something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/_search/samples/queryString
```

You'll get the results in json format.

If you need to customize the default search behaviour check the Elasticsearch documentation on Spring:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/1.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/elasticsearch.repositories.html