# JHipster: Search not working

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster

I generated one application and some entities. Initially its working fine.
Now when I tried to search form any page[[entity].html]

I am getting following error "No mapping found for [id] in order to sort on"

Comment: now i am able to reproduced the same issue. I created one more application and run the application after creating an entity. Then tried to do search it was working. After that I just deleted target folder manually and then run the same application and tried search, and its giving me the above issue. I see some folder related elasticsearch under the target folder. What went wrong? I am not familiar with elastic search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution for now and its working
https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer

Comment: it helps +1.  more details can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400746/elasticsearch-on-jhipster-spring